# datatables and tinymce

Tags: php, tinymce, datatables

How do i enable/show tincymce in datatables?

For every datatables row, I've a textarea which displays html content. I need to show this html content in tincymce instead of a textarea. So if I've ten rows per page, i'll have ten rows of tinymces showing html content.

I'm getting html content from a server but currently showing this in a bare html textarea.

Comment: @Daniel, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Here's what i did:<br/>               `'fnDrawCallback': function(o){            tinyMCE.init({
                    mode : "textareas",
                    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
                    theme : "simple" 
            });
}`<br/> I put the above in the datable.init() call. This works when the existing DB content is wrapped in a textarea and is sent to the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this (Not Tested)

Add a class same class to all your textareas and use it in the `editor_selector` attribute of the `tinyMCE.init` function:

Sample example of multiple selection

[Class selectors/deselectors](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/selector_deselector.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor",
        editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
        <textarea id="content1" name="content1" class="mceEditor" cols="85" rows="10">This will be a editor, since it has a selector class.</textarea>
        <textarea id="content2" name="content2" class="mceEditor" cols="85" rows="10">This will be a editor, since it has a selector class.</textarea>
        <textarea id="content3" name="content3" class="mceNoEditor" cols="85" rows="10">This is not a editor since it has a deselector class.</textarea>
</form>
```

Same thing should work with datatables too...

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm going to assume you're working in asp.net, since you didn't tag this with any programming language.

Now that that's out of the way, lets start by putting all the elements you want to turn into editors in an array:

```
c = new Array('<%= ((UpdatePanel1.FindControl("FormView1")).FindControl("txteditor")).ClientID %>', '...');
```

Then join these together into a tinyMCE-readable string:

```
var sC = c.join();
```

Finally tell in tinyMCE.init() which elements you want to turn into editors:

```
elements: sC
```

Comment: Well sorry for not adding the language tag but am doing this in PHP. But do you think this is gonna work if we are getting the data from serverside?

Comment: @BoCode of course, the only thing that's going to change is the way you generate the array of ids. It's probably a lot easier in php because asp.net adds a ton to the ids, requiring you to use the huge construct in my example.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to render your database content into the textarea elements on server side or after ajax-call (this depends on your system and use case). Now you need to initialize the tinymce editors.

You should look [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22) for a detailed description of what you need to do.

The [TinyMCE FAQ](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ) might be of help too.

Comment: Yes, i'm putting the DB content into the textareas and am displaying them without sweat right now. Question is how do i convert all these textareas into tinymces. if i put <script> tincyMCE.init({mode:'textareas',theme:'simple'});</script>, it does not seem to work. Could it because data is gotten from AJAX call?

Comment: yes, this will prevent your textareas to become editors. you will need to call the init function after your ajax calls are all made